# [] Operator overloading for get and set operation in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, reference, operator-overloading

I'm having the following class:

```
class mem
{
private:
    char _memory[0x10000][9];

public: 
    const (&char)[9] operator [] (int addr);    
}
```

My goal is to be able to use the `mem` class like an array while the implementation will be more complex later. So, I should be able to

- access it like 'mem[0x1234]' to return a reference to an array of 9 chars
- write to it like 'mem[0x1234] = "12345678\0";'

This is what I tried:

```
#include "mem.h"

const (&char)[9] mem::operator [] (int addr)
{
    return &_memory[addr];
}
```

However, it says that the method "must have a return value", which I thought I have defined as `(&char)[9]`, but as this definition I get the error message "expected an identifier".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the following way

```
#include "mem.h"

const char ( & mem::operator [] (int addr) const )[9]
{
    return _memory[addr];
}
```

also you can add a non-constant operator

```
char ( & mem::operator [] (int addr) )[9]
{
    return _memory[addr];
}
```

The class definition will look like

```
class mem
{
private:
    char _memory[0x10000][9];

public: 
    const char ( & operator [] (int addr) const )[9];    
    char ( & operator [] (int addr) )[9];    
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`operator[]` is a function taking int

```
operator[](int addr)
```

that returns a reference

```
& operator[](int addr)
```

to an array of length 9

```
(&operator[](int addr))[9]
```

of `const char`

```
const char (&operator[](int addr))[9]
```

---

That said, don't do that. Use `typedef`s to simplify:

```
typedef const char (&ref9)[9];
ref9 operator[](int addr);
```

---

That said, don't do that either.

```
std::array<std::array<char, 9>, 0x10000> _memory;
const std::array<char, 9>& operator[](int addr);
```